# How can I prevent Laravel from setting a session cookie when the user is not auth?

Tags: laravel, session-cookies, laravel-session

By default, Laravel sets a Cookie called [APP_NAME]_session on every request. It's used for features as `redirect()->back()`.

This cookie prevents my cache mechanism to work properly (FastCGI, Varnish, you name it)

If I'm one hundred percent sure I won't need it, is there a way to remove this cookie when the user is not auth, without preventing them to log in as usual ?

I'd like to show a different menu when my user is authed, so I can't apply a different middleware on some routes.

Answer (score 3):

I created a new class, which extends the StartSession Middleware (referenced in `app/Middleware/Kernel.php`, inside the `web` group).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class StartSession extends \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
{
    /**
     * Start the session for the given request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param  Session  $session
     * @return Session
     */
    protected function startSession(Request $request, $session): Session
    {
        return tap($session, function ($session) use ($request) {
            $session->setRequestOnHandler($request);

            if (Cookie::get(config("session.cookie"))) {
                $session->start();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Add the session cookie to the application response.
     *
     * @param Response $response
     * @param Session $session
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addCookieToResponse(Response $response, Session $session)
    {
        if (!auth()->check()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->sessionIsPersistent($config = $this->manager->getSessionConfig())) {
            $response->headers->setCookie(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie(
                $session->getName(), $session->getId(), $this->getCookieExpirationDate(),
                $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'] ?? false,
                $config['http_only'] ?? true, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

The two importants part are :

- in startSession() :

```
if (Cookie::get(config("session.cookie"))) {
    $session->start();
}
```

This part prevents the session from being created when the user wasn't already authed.

- in addCookieToResponse() :

```
if (!auth()->check()) {
    return;
}
```

This part prevents Laravel from setting the cookie as long as the user is not authed.